# Is it allowed on StackOverflow to provide a link to a project website if it contains a question specifying information?

Tags: discussion, advertising, hyperlinks, rules

May I link to my website (the project home or my blog) page which contains diagrams etc. context specifying data (which is definitely useful to attach to a question but hardly optimal to rewrite into a question body)? Isn't it considered an advertisement?

Answer (score 3):

As long as it is truly on topic and truly helpful, yes this is fine. Be sure to clearly state that it is your own website.

I would post a brief summary of the information in the answer, and then post the link for "more information".

Comment: +1 (in 2 hours when I get more votes): This is what I would do

Comment: There, fixed that for you.

Comment: @gf: what? Sorry I'm lost

Comment: The +1 ;) @Josh

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Jon B. I would do something like:

---

[The following post on my website](http://www.google.com/profiles/ivan.mashchenko) explains in detail what you're trying to do. To summarize that post:

> Paste in here some content from your
>   site, the most relevant part which
>   addresses the user's question. Doing
>   so allows people to see that your
>   answer is relevant with a glance
>   rather than having to go to your site,
>   as well as mirroring the content here
>   on StackOverflow so if your site is
>   down/goes away, the content remains
>   and the answer is still substantial.
>   This should help make it less blantant
>   self promotion and reduce/eliminate
>   downvotes.

Comment: (Except obviously link to the actual content :-)